# Accessing Javascript nested object returned by Laravel

Tags: javascript, object

For some reasons I can not access name from category object it says undefined

```
 datas:  [{
              "id": 3,
               "title": "public",
               "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:37:28",
               "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:37:28",
               "announcements": [{
                            "id": 3,
                            "user_id": 37,
                            "title": "Jumapili 13-01-2019",
                            "category_id": 13,
                            "body": "Saa 1030 asubuhi Consequuntur autem veniam ut voluptatibus. Qui impedit et ipsam est veritatis dolores. Voluptate quos harum eos nisi aut. Officiis nemo occaecati voluptas id modi. Sit omnis est autem aliquam sint quam libero.",
                            "end_date": "2019-01-12 02:56:15",
                            "live": 0,
                            "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                            "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                            "pivot": {"viewer_id": 3, "viewable_id": 3, "viewable_type": "App\\Announcement"},
                            "category": {
                                "id": 13,
                                "user_id": 38,
                                "name": "et",
                                "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                                "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15"
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
```

when I try to access it on the Vue component I get undefined

```
  div class="public" v-for="dataSet in  datas">
         <div v-for="announcements in dataSet">
            <dl v-for="announcement in announcements">
                <dt class="category" 
                    v-text="announcement.category"></dt>
                <h3 v-text="announcement.title"></h3>
                <dd v-text="announcement.body"></dd>
            </dl>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `announcement` is an object, and not JSON? Try `console.log`ging it

Comment: Typo - `announcements.category` - `announcements` is plural

Comment: You may be correct this my be a JSON thing so please how do I go about accessing category name

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the vue component in this way:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app', //the id of tour html
data: {
datas:  [{
          "id": 3,
           "title": "public",
           "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:37:28",
           "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:37:28",
           "announcements": [{
                        "id": 3,
                        "user_id": 37,
                        "title": "Jumapili 13-01-2019",
                        "category_id": 13,
                        "body": "Saa 1030 asubuhi Consequuntur autem veniam ut voluptatibus. Qui impedit et ipsam est veritatis dolores. Voluptate quos harum eos nisi aut. Officiis nemo occaecati voluptas id modi. Sit omnis est autem aliquam sint quam libero.",
                        "end_date": "2019-01-12 02:56:15",
                        "live": 0,
                        "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                        "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                        "pivot": {"viewer_id": 3, "viewable_id": 3, "viewable_type": "App\\Announcement"},
                        "category": {
                            "id": 13,
                            "user_id": 38,
                            "name": "et",
                            "created_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15",
                            "updated_at": "2019-01-12 02:36:15"
                        }
                    }]
                }]
  }
})
```

Comment: the cue part shared is just the template section only the script section is being pulled from backend and that datas variable you see has extracted from Vuejs developer tool web browser extension